# Is there any difference between the following?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how actually memory allocation works and I have a question.

```
var a = {name: 'John', age: '20'};
console.log(a.name);
```

and

```
var a = {name: 'John', age: '20'};
var name = a.name;
console.log(name);
```

I know that both of them give the same result, but I want to know whether the memory usage of both of these codes is the same or not.

Comment: You have tagged three different languages. Why?

Comment: Three languages *and* a platform!

Comment: Well the code isn't C or C++, so those tags removed.

Comment: Whether the memory usage is equal or not depends on the degree of optimization being performed. Which depends on many facters (like how good the implementation is), so really your question has no simple answer.

Comment: Whatever engine you are using will treat it differently. I would not worry about memory unless you are really seeing a huge problem.

Comment: There is no question here. If you really care about memory allocation, read through the docs for the engines you want to learn about because each one will do things a little bit differently (V8, Gecko, Servo, etc). If not, this is the kind of information that is utterly useless for actually writing JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each declared variable will occupy a space in your memory, in the first example:

```
var a = {name: 'John' , age: '20'};
console.log(a.name);
```

*var a* is declared and thus a space is reserved for it, and in the second example:

```
var a = {name: 'John' , age: '20'};
var name = a.name;
console.log(name);
```

Besides from declaring *var a*, you have also reserved another space for *var name*

This link from MDN can provide a better insight:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Hope this was useful for you!

Comment: " which holds a pointer to a.name, in this case if a.name changes you will see and update in the name variable." this is simply false.

Comment: you are right, its just a reference, let me edit that and remove the unrequested info